# ScrollView allows dragging content. How can this be disabled?

Tags: qt, animation, qml, drag, qtquick2

The content of a QML `ScrollView` can be dragged using the mouse or touch gestures. The same is true for the content of `ListView`s, at least in the example I have. 
And it is even possible to do so when the content fits into the `ScrollView` and no scrollbars are displayed. In this case, after releasing the mouse button, the content item moves back to it's original place. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the property [`boundsBehavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#boundsBehavior-prop) which `ScrollView` inherits from `Flickable`. Setting it to `Flickable.StopAtBounds` should do the trick. See also the property [`interactive`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#interactive-prop).

Comment: ScrollView doesn't have this property

Comment: Those are properties of Flickable, which is also responsible for the dragging behaviour. If your ScrollView (from Quick Controls 1 or Quick Controls 5.x) wraps a Flickable (or a derived type like ListView) you can set these properties to disable scrolling.

Comment: Vernat is right. `ScrollView` does not inherit `Flickable` in Qt6.4 and the wrapped items have nothing to do with it, so how to disable it? E.g. just put a ScrollView and put Rectangles into it to check

Comment: This answer is [plain wrong](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview-members.html).